# Are stats from D&D Miniatures compatible with D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-miniatures-game

I am a bit confused about *D&D Miniatures* and regular D&D. I only have the Starter Set from D&D Miniatures 4th ed (I think) and the *Castle Ravenloft* boardgame.

Do the stats, levels, races, powers, etc. of the characters/monsters in the minis game match the ones in those numerous books of D&D 4e? How about the *Castle Ravenloft* boardgame?

I should mention that I've never played the RPG version before... but you probably have figured that out by yourselves.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you looking to play D&D 4th edition with these minis? Or is this just a matter of curiosity? What would resolving this confusion let you do that you can't now and would like to?

Comment: If the question @SevenSidedDie links *isn't* the same as your question, can you please explain what's different? They look like pretty much the same question to me, so I've voted to mark this question as a duplicate -- which is fine, if that "duplicate" actually is a duplicate and answers your question. But if not, let us know and we can update this question to make it clear how it's different, and remove the 'duplicate' mark (if that gets applied before you clarify).

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to the post. I am a bit clarified now. But, the characters from the Minis and Castle Ravenloft are found in the Monster's Manual of D&D RPG?